# Initialize an interface object within service

Tags: android, user-interface, android-service

I have an interface called `ServerStateListener`. I'm starting a service called `Hotspot Service` from my activity `ZimHostActivity`.

I've implemented this interface in my activity to get the callback. Now, I want to initialize the interface object within my Service i.e. `Hotspot Service`.

Since service has it's own context, this is what I tried to do in its `onCreate()`:

`serverStateListener = (ServerStateListener) this;`

But I'm getting this error:

`HotspotService cannot be cast to org.kiwix.kiwixmobile.webserver.ServerStateListener`

I've also tried `getApplicationContext()` and `getBaseContext()`. How can I initialize the interface instance within my Service?

Comment: https://medium.com/@ankit_aggarwal/ways-to-communicate-between-activity-and-service-6a8f07275297

Answer (score 0):

1-Create a class extends from Application and define context like this:

```
public class AppController extends Application {

private static AppController mInstance;
private static Context context;

public static Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

public static AppController getmInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
    context = getApplicationContext(); 
}
}
```

2-define this class in manifest

```
<application
        android:name=".AppController"
        .......
 />
```

3-Call context:

```
serverStateListener = (ServerStateListener) AppController.getContext();
```

Comment: That's a memory leak.